# how to add listview within listview all dynamically(like treeview) in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

1. Fruits

   1. apple
   2. banana
2. Veg

   1. ladies finger
   2. carrot.

Need something like this, where Fruits are multi select but veg are not(select only one). The items are objects and not just a string. How to load this into a treeview or listview of multidimensional array?

Comment: Please take a walk around the StackOverflow help to learn how to better ask a question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you want make Group ListView?